# How can I provide role control with Discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I have two roles on my server. One is the **Subscriber** role and the other is the **VIP Subscriber** role. How can I list people who have **VIP Subscriber** role but not regular **Subscriber** role with command?

I hope I was able to explain what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

`guild.roles.cache.find((role) => ...)` finds the first role from the server that meets the `role.name.toLowerCase() === 'vip subscriber'` condition. `toLowerCase()`: converts the string to lowercase letters.

`(await guild.members.fetch()).filter((member) => ...)`: Fetches all members from the server, finds all members with the given role. `member.roles.cache.has(vip_role.id)`: returns true if the member has the specified role.

`vip_members.forEach((member) => { ... })`: Loops through members with specified role. You can do what you want with the member inside the loop.

```
const { guild } = message;
const vip_role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name.toLowerCase() === 'vip subscriber');
const vip_members = (await guild.members.fetch()).filter((member) => member.roles.cache.has(vip_role.id));
vip_members.forEach((member) => {
    console.log(member.user.tag);
});
```

Comment: Explain why your code works and how you came to that method, don't just dump it

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```js
const vip = message.guild.roles.cache.get('roleID') // prefer ID for single server
// or
// const vip = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'VIP Subscriber')
const subscriberRoleID = 'roleID2';
const peopleOnlyWithVIP = vip.members.filter(member => !member.roles.cache.has(subscriberRoleID)); // Final list that you want
// Returns a discord.js Collection
```

### Explanation

First we get the role vip subscriber using id or its name, now we declare subscriber role id, finally we use [`<Role>#members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members) method to get the Collection of Members having that role and filter those members who do **not** have regular subscriber role (using `<GuildMemberRoleManager>.cache.has` method)

Hope you understood the solution!